# Taking sine of each row for a specific column python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset with continuous values. The values for last two column is for regression prediction and I want to calculate sine of each row for these two columns and put this new dataset to another file. How can I create this new dataset?

---

Edit: The code that I tried is below. But I got error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. How can I solve it?

```
import numpy as np

for i in range (1,4):
  f1=open('...'+str(i)+'.dat','r')
  f2=open('.....'+str(i)+'.dat','w')

  for line in f1:
   line=line.split(' ')
   print np.sin(line[:,-2:])
   f2.write()
  f1.close()
  f2.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What is your specific *programming* question? Where is your code?

Comment: Please define dataframe as toyexample to work with <3

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a sample data ? Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how exactly your data looks, I'll just have to make some on my own...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> M = np.arange(20).reshape((4,5))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

To get all rows of the last two columns, you can use `[:,-2:]`:

```
>>> M[:,-2:]
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 8,  9],
       [13, 14],
       [18, 19]])
```

Then, just apply the sine function with `numpy.sin`:

```
>>> np.sin(M[:,-2:])
array([[ 0.14112001, -0.7568025 ],
       [ 0.98935825,  0.41211849],
       [ 0.42016704,  0.99060736],
       [-0.75098725,  0.14987721]])
```

---

About your updated/newly added code: You are getting a `TypeError` because your `line` variable is not a `numpy` array, and much less a 2D array/matrix but just a simple one-dimensional plain-Python list. You *could* still use `np.sin` with that list, but you will have to slice using just `[-2:]` since it's one-dimensional. Also, the `f2.write()` does not make sense; you are writing nothing to the file and instead just printing the result to std-out. Also, you are overwriting your input file; not sure if that is intended. Instead, you might want to use `numpy.loadtxt` and `numpy.savetxt` to read and save the entire data set.

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("input.dat", delimiter=",")
result = np.sin(data[:,-2:])
np.savetxt("output.dat", result, fmt="%.2f", delimiter=",")
```

Comment: I take the error when I apply this.
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: If I want to make this operation for all files in a directory, what I have to do?

Comment: @gEngW This seems to be an entirely new question and not really connected to this one, so you should open a new topic.